# java substring returning empty

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm attempting to take a substring of a string txt and then set another portion of that string to a value, however whenever I try to set voltage[t] with the double value of the substring, I'm getting an empty string error.  Here's the part of the code where I'm getting the error:

```
if(txt.substring(0,1).equals("1")) {
    //Voltage button pressed(S3)
                //=====================================================================

    text3.setText(txt.substring(1));
    voltage[t] = (Double.parseDouble(text3.getText()));
}
```

Anyone know why this error would be occurring?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Edit:
Here is the exact exception I'm receiving:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at UartApp$11.run(UartApp.java:728)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
```

The error occurs on line 728

Also, here's the code I'm using to convert the int and adding the "1".  The microcontroller is programmed in C:

```
        char *p, text[32];
        int i = readADC(POT);

        sprintf(text,"1%d", i);
        p = text;
        UartTxString(p);  //Sends string out
```

Comment: If `txt` is the string `1`, your `if` statement is true and `text3` is updated to the string following the `1`, i.e. to an empty string. So, perhaps, `txt` doesn't contain what you think it does, if you thought `text3` would not be empty.

Comment: @shmosel Hopefully `"1"` else our understanding of the error is wrong.  As per OP *attempting to take the value after that first digit for the second string*

Comment: If I just attempt to output txt.substring(1), I get the correct value posted to the text box, however it just won't let me parse it to a double.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I was initially confused by "empty string error", but then I realized OP's referring to `java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String` thrown when parsing an empty string. Or a string with only whitespace.

Comment: @TestyTest What happens if do `Double.parseDouble(txt.substring(1))`?

Comment: @shmosel in what part of the code exactly?  The textbox entry asks for a string input, so I wouldn't be able to put it there.

Comment: Where you're assigning to `voltage[t]`.

Comment: @TestyTest based upon my answer below, it shows that what you are trying to do should work, but I feel that there is something else going on that you are not tell us.  What value of `txt` are you using?

Comment: txt is being sent from the potentiometer of a pic microcontroller.  It is from an integer value.

Comment: @TestyTest I'm racking my head right now...  That's definitely some odd behavior based on the code provided... What type is `txt`?  Is it just a regular `String`, or is it some other string-like type (that happens to be mutable)?

Comment: So, I attempted to just pull txt.substring(1,2) after the initial check and it gave me an out of bounds error, so I attempted txt.substring(0,1) and it returns a value of 1 every time... I have no idea why or how though.

Comment: @TestyTest What happens if you perform `txt.substring(1,2)` immediately *before* the initial check?  Is the result the same or different as what you just saw *after* the initial check?

Comment: Looks like it gives an out of bounds error there as well.  So I just posted txt to the text box and got a value of 9680, however the console is showing a value of 19680...  I really have no idea what's going on right now.

Comment: @TestyTest What type is `txt`?  Is it a plain old `String`?  Or some other string-like type?  *(I'm wondering if mutability and/or implicit type conversion is affecting the results)*

Comment: @TestyTest Hmm... In a different vein, I just noticed that your stacktrace indicates your application uses synchronization... might there be some concurrency -related issue?  *(perhaps another thread assigning a different string object to the `txt` reference variable, or some sort of discrepancy between the local cache and main memory / other thread caches?)*

Comment: Now that I think about it, the degree of bizarre-ness you're observing is a classic indicator of a concurrency / synchronization issue...

Comment: @TestyTest I've got an early morning tomorrow, so I'm about to hit the hay.  Best of luck in solving this!  If the synchronization angle doesn't pan out, you might just try saving everything and restarting your IDE.  It's a long shot, but that has actually worked for me once or twice before to solve really weird problems...

Comment: That is entirely possible.  My teacher gave us a function to use to read inputs from the microcontroller and just kind of hand waved a discussion about synchronization.  When I attempt to use the same code for the temperature sensor and replace the "1" with a "2", it actually makes 2 logs even though the code only calls for one.  It logs the value "2"(similarly to how the other code logs "1"), and then logs the temp value.

Comment: @Travis Just wanted to give you an update.  The reason the code didn't work was because the function that reads the String input from the board reads it a char at a time, so if the value was 123, it would read each digit as its own separate string, that's why it was reading the first "1", and then taking that as the full string value, which was causing the error when taking the substring(1).  The way that my professor told me to get around it is to adjust the function and send the value as raw data, and then convert it.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @TestyTest Glad you got it working!  Just out of curiosity, did you happen to figure it why it was still able to display a multi-character string (e.g. 19680 ...see one of your comments above) even though it only read in a single character at a time?

Answer (score -1):

If the code you provided is complete and representable, then `Double.parseDouble(...)` would throw an exception indicating an empty string if and only if `txt` is the string `"1"` (and nothing else).

Assuming you want to get the double value of `"1"`, then the way you would fix this is by changing `text3.setText(txt.substring(1));` to `text3.setText(txt.substring(0,1));`.

If instead what you want to do is to get the double value of anything in the string after the leading `"1"`, then I think you may have a problem elsewhere in your code--wherever it is that you set the value of `txt`.  If so, could you post that code as well so that we can take a look?

*(I think what may be happening is that you intended to prepend `"1"` to `txt`, but instead accidentally replaced the value of `txt` with `"1"` entirely)*

---

EDIT:

The problem may be with `text3` instead.

Try this.  Replace

```
voltage[t] = (Double.parseDouble(text3.getText()));
```

with

```
voltage[t] = (Double.parseDouble(txt.substring(1)));
```

---

EDIT #2:

If the above replacement did not fix the problem, then it **must** be true that `txt` is exactly the string `"1"` (and nothing else) within this scope.  The problem may lie in how you are prepending the `'1'` to `txt`.

Comment: @TestyTest what is the exact exception / error and associated message that you are getting?  (quote it somewhere here, if possible)

Comment: @TestyTest Also, if you are still getting the same answer even after making that change, then `txt` **must** be only the string `"1"` (and nothing else) in this scope.  How exactly are you prepending a `'1'` to `txt`?  There may be something going on there...

Comment: Well, the error is pretty much exactly what you said it was.  Nothing additional particularly helpful in the stacktrace... And the C code that forms and outputs the string looks perfectly fine too...